# When do I need the Windows SDK and what is .NET for?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, c, winapi

I am a student and after taking some introductory programming courses in Java, C, and just finishing up a book on C++, I would like to start developing applications for Windows.

I have done my best to page through google and find the answers I need, but I seem to be at a loss.

When would I need the Windows SDK over just the regular API?
And what is .NET and why would I need it?
What is so special about C# and should I use that over C/C++?

Comment: +1 - suggest community Wiki for this

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> When would I need the Windows SDK over just the regular API?

The SDK includes headers, libraries, tools, etc., that give you access to the API (and to .NET, for that matter). For example, a typical API-based program will start with `#include <windows.h>` -- but without the SDK, you don't have a copy of Windows.h to include. Likewise, the SDK includes the compilers (the same actual compilers included in the current version of Visual C++), linkers, debuggers, etc., necessary to actually build an API-based program.

> And what is .NET and why would I need it?

.NET is a couple of things: a virtual machine that executes code in what Microsoft calls "intermediate language" (IL). It's also a (large) library of code in IL for everything from window management and drawing to communications, system management, etc.

You'd need it primarily if you were writing code in a .NET-based language such as C#,  VB.NET, etc.

> What is so special about C# and should I use that over C/C++?

C# is (by far) the preferred language for .NET development. Microsoft did develop  .NET versions of Visual BASIC, and something at least quite similar to C++, but both tend to lag behind C# (at best).

So, if you're developing code specifically for Windows (especially if it includes a GUI), C# is probably your first choice. Microsoft does a lot more to support it than to support C or C++. That shows up in better support in both libraries and tooling.

The primary argument in favor of using C or C++ would probably be that you're developing primarily for Linux, and then porting the code to Windows. You can still do such development in C# if you want to (e.g., you can run C# and .NET under Linux using Mono), but especially if you're doing the development work under Linux, you lose most of the advantages.

On the other hand, if your code doesn't involve a GUI anyway, you might be able to write portable C or C++, and just compile it under both Windows and Linux. In such a case, using C# could involve extra work, such as having to install Mono to run the code under Linux--not a terribly difficult task, but even a fairly easy installation can be more work than no installation at all.

Comment: +1 - nice answer. I think "flavor of the month" is a bit dismissive given we are now at .Net 4.0 - this is more than just a fad at Microsoft, it's their strategic direction for enterprise development, replacing Win32 for all but the most specialized usage.  To contrast: .Net Remoting was "flavor of the month", now they want all to use WCF, for example.  btw Windows SDK combines Platform SDK and .Net Framework SDK into a single package.

Comment: @Steve: fair enough -- modified.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was amazingly helpful!

Comment: Why Windows SDK cannot be installed without .NET Framework? I tried to install SDK but it stopped and threw an error that I didn't have some .NET components. Here's my question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446016/problems-with-computer-after-installing-net-framework-is-it-possible-to-instal

Answer (score -3):

Windows SDK is a low-level framework for developing applications specifically for Windows. You could use it for your development. However, the APIs are low-level and a little difficult to use and maintain.

Alternatively, you could use .Net. .Net is a framework that includes runtime support for your application. It has many packages, I am sure you will find something useful in .Net. .Net needs a runtime for executation and is not compiled natively to the platform. However, it is easier for software development mostly because the APIs are higher level.

C# is the recommended language for Windows specific programming, specially on .Net. Not that it is the only language, you could also use C/C++, but they are not supported by Microsoft actively. For example, if you use C#, creating a GUI application could just a few mouse clicks. Using C++, you would need to manage your windows instances.

Typically, you would only use C/C++ for Windows programming if you are doing cross-platform programming or some low-level stuffs.

Comment: "Typically, you would only use C/C++ for Windows programming if you are doing cross-platform programming or some low-level stuffs." - I have to object to this statement, as people (including me) use C++ for application development (and other things) extensively.

Comment: Also, there is no such language as C/C++. They're two different languages. Also, C++ is in fact supported by Microsoft actively. The Visual C++ team have their own blog (blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog) and have released Visual C++ 2010 that has partial support for C++0x, the latest version of C++. If you're comfortable with C++, it's more than fine to use C++ for Windows programming.

Comment: "Using C++, you would need to manage your windows instances." - I also have to object to this statement, as there are C++ techniques that allow you to not worry about managing resources using idioms like RAII.

Comment: "Windows SDK is a low-level framework for developing applications specifically for Windows." - This I **don't** object to. :-)

Comment: Visual C++ is not the same as C++.

Comment: Well, anything that you put on C++ to encapsulate low-level stuffs, for example the RAII that you put on is not a part of the language. You still have to do it, but just hidden somewhere.

Comment: The syntax is similar, but Visual C++ is designed for Windows. It has things like handles not available for C++.

Comment: @In silico: I'm sure what he meant by C/C++ is C or C++.

Comment: @Kinderchocolate: Visual C++ is an IDE, not a programming language. You're most likely referring to Managed C++ or C++/CLI.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant Managed C++.

Comment: Oh, okay, I misunderstood that part.

Comment: a very biased answer towards C#, a programmer wanting to embark on windows programming should be given the facts and allowed to make their own decisions on what suits them best.

Comment: @Paul: Visual C++ is the compiler, the IDE being Visual Studio :) </nitpick>